# add a volume for h2 database with jdbc connection

Tags: docker, h2

I have a java application that works on a h2 local database. If I want to build an image to containerize this project I used this DockerFile:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:11
VOLUME /tmp
COPY h2/ /opt/h2
RUN ["cd", " /opt/h2/bin"]
RUN ["chmod", " +x", " h2.sh"]
RUN mkdir /opt/app
RUN ["cd", " /opt/app"]
COPY PersonPersist/ /opt/app
ADD PersonPersist/target/Person-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8082:8082
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", " app.jar"]
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

I get an Error

> ERROR: failed to solve: process "cd  /opt/h2/bin" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

I am not sure about if the volume local in my computer should contain the h2 db files.
Normally I must type:

```
docker volume create tmp
docker run -dp 127.0.0.1:3000:3000 --mount type=volume,src=tmp,target=/tmp myopenjdk
```

Another point is: if I starts h2 .jar on my computer locally I get a explorer web interface where I can choose my local database. Is it possible to do the same approach on the host machine. Something like phpMyAdmin but with h2 instead. I will try to change my app with mysql so that I can test both and post some outputs

Comment: Often in Docker it will be easier to manage data if you use a separate database container; maybe use Docker Compose to start a PostgreSQL container, and if your application is using Spring Boot, set a `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` environment variable to point at it.  This makes it much easier to run multiple copies of your application if you need to, and avoids concerns around accidentally deleting your data when you upgrade your application code.